# Iframe not showing on IE7 and 8?

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, html

Iframe not showing on IE7 and 8 on my PC but showing on all other non IE browsers. and working on my friend's IE7 and 8.

Comment: Is this from a page that you wrote yourself?

Comment: @JNK - http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe this not working on my PC's IE

Comment: @metal gear solid - try setting the width to a number instead of a percentage.  IE doesn't like percentages sometimes within iframes.

Comment: @JNK- but it's working fine on my friend's IE7 and 8.

Comment: @metal gear solid - Did it work?  It could be an issue with your install.

Comment: works fine on all 5 of my browsers

Comment: @jer.salamon, @JNK - The problem is with my IE only. Iframe were not showing on my IE7 then i upgraded 7 to IE8 but any Iframe still not showing on IE8. this is not a problem with any particular page. my IE not displaying any Iframe on any site.

Comment: does it show 100% nothing as if the tag is ignored?

Comment: problem solved i reset the whole settings http://antivirus.about.com/od/securitytips/ht/ie7reset.htm